# how to check the MySQL56 service of window 10 using c# .net

Tags: c#

I have try to check **MySQL56** service from my pc to other pc using c# .net.
The all pc connected by LAN.

I have tried below code:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MySQL56", "IP"); <br>
 if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) <br>
      Console.WriteLine("Service started"); <br>
 if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) <br>
      Console.WriteLine("Service stoped");
```

it's work for some IP. But it's not work for all pc (through error Access denied).

Comment: Right click the Application and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: we have try to this way. but it's not work. We have created window form application for this project.